# How to create Microsoft.StickyNotes.exe shortcut in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, modern-ui, sticky-notes, file-shortcut

All I want to do is create either a shortcut or a copy of Microsoft.StickyNotes.exe so that I can put it in my QuickLaunch. Whenever I try to do this I get this error:

> This application can only run in the context of an app container.

I've searched for a solution but nothing I've tried works. Can someone please show the right direction to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open Run dialog box. Type `shell:AppsFolder` in that box. Find the sticky notes app icon. Right click on that icon and select 'Create Shortcut' option as follows:

[image: Create_StickyNotes_Shortcut.PNG]

Alternatively, right click on desktop. Select New > Shortcut. Paste the following in the path:

```
explorer shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
```

And name your shortcut as StickyNotes.

- **Sources:**

  - [InfoPackets: How to Place Microsoft Edge Shortcut on the Desktop](https://www.infopackets.com/news/9699/how-place-microsoft-edge-shortcut-desktop)
  - [TenForums: How to Create a Microsoft Edge Shortcut in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7755-create-shortcut-microsoft-edge-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: @I_am_Jacks_colon: I've done it on your behalf, good sir.